# Which Kickstart commands and options cannot be %included?

Tags: centos, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I'm using Kickstart to automate a CentOS 7 installation and I'd like to create a common [Kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-kickstart-installations.html) file so I can `%include` it. After some testing it seems like some commands (like `text`) cannot be included, but I can't find any official documentation which lists them.

I found a Kickstart file in a [mailing list thread](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhelv5-list/2009-March/msg00108.html) which says:

> ```
> # These five entries must be contained in this file to be initially parsed.
> install
> cmdline
> lang en_US.UTF-8
> keyboard us
> nfs --server server.my.com --dir /var/ftp/pub/kickstartes5/Redhat/
> ```

I [read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144083/6495) that Anaconda parses the Kickstart file, runs the `%pre` script, and then re-parses the file. I also found this in the [pykickstart documentation](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst#chapter-4-pre-installation-script) on `%pre`:

> You can add commands to run on the system immediately after the ks.cfg has been parsed and the lang, keyboard, and url options have been processed.

It looks like Anaconda uses [Dracut to do some Kickstart parsing](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/blob/master/dracut/parse-kickstart) as well, but I'm not sure what the implications are for a Kickstart file author... there's [some code](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/blob/master/dracut/parse-kickstart#L234) that says:

```
dracutCmds = {
    'cdrom': Cdrom,
    'harddrive': HardDrive,
    'nfs': NFS,
    'url': URL,
    'updates': Updates,
    'mediacheck': MediaCheck,
    'driverdisk': DriverDisk,
    'network': Network,
    'cmdline': DisplayMode,
    'graphical': DisplayMode,
    'text': DisplayMode,
    'bootloader': Bootloader,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some kickstart commands represent setup tasks that have to be handled *before* the main installer can start, so they're only handled inside `dracut`. The ones I know of are:

- Set display mode: `text`, `graphical`, `cmdline`
- Load driver disks: `driverdisk`
- Load installer updates: `updates`
- Check install media: `mediacheck`

So those probably won't work in an `%include`, unless the `%include` target is visible inside `dracut` (like, say, if you injected it into the initrd, or put it on the same device as the kickstart..)

If you need to use one of those but it can't be in the main kickstart, you could try using the [corresponding boot options](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/blob/rhel7-branch/docs/boot-options.txt) instead:

- Set display mode: `inst.text`, `inst.graphical`, `inst.cmdline`
- Load driver disks: `inst.dd=<url>`
- Load installer updates: `inst.updates=<url>`
- Check install media: `rd.live.check`